# Crop A Pdf Using Code

Tags: graphics, pdfcrop

I have a .tex file that produces a pdf of one page. This pdf contains some information that doesn't fill the full page and leave a big white space.

Is there any code / command / environment that modifies the resulting pdf (or produces an image)  so that it deletes the white space.

This is an example of my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm , right = 2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white, title=Bla]
    Bla Ble
\end{tcolorbox}

\section{Tiz}
Aw
\end{document}
```

Comment: the standalone class wil make a pdf sized to closely fit the content, or several pdf tools can crop a pdf  pdfcrop for example, most are wrappers aroud ghostscript

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you provide an example using standalone class? .

Comment: look for `\documentclass{standalone}`  here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standalone

Comment: but `\documentclass{standalone}\begin{document}hello\end{document}`  is a complete example

Comment: I add a .tex example, could you show me how implement the standalone class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white, title=Bla]
    Bla Ble
\end{tcolorbox}

\section{Tiz}
Aw
\end{document}
```

This crops very closely, the class has several options to add padding or other things to control the output.

Comment: Hey, If You Could Show Me (I don't Know) how change border / margin of Output ?

Comment: there is a manual `texdoc standalone` there are _lots_ of optiions, but try `\documentclass[varwidth,border=1cm]{standalone}` @user232560

Comment: Thanks for your help.